# Idiomatic way to replace the whole line with clipboard content

Tags: vim, clipboard

I use `vim-gtk` so pasting from clipboard is as simple as pasting the content of the `"+` register. For each line I could replace it with clipboard content as follows:

```
1. V
2. d
3. o
4. <ESC>
5. pasting from clipboard (bound to some shortcut)
```

The disadvantages I see here are these:

1. Switching between normal and insert modes (step 3)
2. Messing up registers with garbage content (step 2)

So what is the idiomatic way to replace a line with content of clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different things you could do. I don't know if any of them are *more idiomatic*, but they're shorter.

1. `dd` is a little bit more idiomatic than `Vd`, so I would recommend using that instead. `ddO<C-r>+<esc>` is a little shorter than `ddO<esc>"+p`
2. You could do `"+pkdd` but this isn't really any shorter. It does however stay entirely in normal mode, which is nice.
3. You can just do `V"+p`, which is the shortest way without a mapping.

Of course, if you do this frequently enough, you could always make your own mapping, using any of these methods. For example:

```
nnoremap <leader>p V"+p
```

`<leader>` is jut a tool to make defining your own mappings more convenient. For example, if you were to do:

```
nnoremap p V"+p
```

then you lose the ability to call the default `p`. Leader is basically a namespace for your own mappings. [More information can be found here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/845/2920).

Comment: Can you explain why you used `<Leader>` here?

Comment: @St.Antario Sure! See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Your use case (replace one line with clipboard contents) would be `"+grr`.